# Correct way to ask someone to answer their phone?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

> 1. Are you going to take that?
> 2. Are you going to answer that?
> 3. Are you going to pick the call?

Which of the above phrases can be used or is there a better way of saying that?

Comment: If the phone can be heard, simply "Could you get that?" is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is OK as it is, though some people might add **call**:

> Are you going to take that **call**?

The third needs a small addition:

> Are you going to pick **up** that call?

or better

> Are you going to [pick up the phone](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick%20up%20the%20phone%2C%20pick%20up%20a%20call&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpick%20up%20the%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpick%20up%20a%20call%3B%2Cc0)?

They are all OK, but in an informal setting the middle one would be my preferred option.